# Float reference only appears when using [h] here float placement

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, positioning, templates

I'm typesetting an article using PNAS' template for two-column articles:
http://www.pnas.org/misc/PNASTWO.CLS

My problem is that if I include a figure or table:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{my figure}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

and reference my figure or table,

```
I now reference Figure \ref{fig:myfig}, a decent figure
```

the Figure number does not appear:

> I now reference Figure  , a decent figure

However, if I specify float placement with the

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

option, the number appears:

> I now reference Figure 1, a decent figure

[tbh], [thbp] will not work, but all variants starting with [h] give float number, like [htb]. Pdflatex does not give any warnings when the float reference do not show, not even the normal ??.

The problem with using [h] is that the [h] figure placement is sub-optimal, making my article longer than the 6-page limit for PNAS.

The pnastwo.cls style file is behind this somehow, because when using a normal article style the reference numbers appear.

I'm not asking anyone to correct the pnas style file, but I would be glad if anyone has any ideas about what is happening here.

Comment: Very hard to tell since we do not know what `pnastwo.cls` is. Perhaps someone has done something not particularly clever. Try `\caption{bla bla\label{fig}}`, some journal styles does not comply to standard LaTeX

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal document showing the problem.  When I try to put one together, I have no problems with numbering and references to the figures.

Comment: daleif: Your suggestion worked! Putting the label within the caption solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Sigh ........ :-)

Comment: Worked for me with placing the `\label` _after_ `\caption{}`, too...

Comment: daleif: another unlikely visitor was helped by this suggestion. \label after \caption{} worked only for the figure*-environment, not for the figure-environment.